# Perl utf8 newline replacement

Tags: regex, perl, twitter

EDIT:
Sorry! Seems the weird line break behaviour for arabic and other text is due to something else entirely. Unfortunately I noticed it the same time I was playing with this script.

---

I'm trying to reformat the text field given by TTYtter in Perl. (Source [here](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/dist2/2.1.00.txt))

The text is defined as "The actual UTF-8 text of the status update. See [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb/blob/master/lib/twitter-text/regex.rb) for details on what is currently considered valid characters." (From Twitter dev pages).

Using

```
$txtin = $ref->{'text'};
$txtin =~ s/\\n\s*/ \\ /g;
```

Strips out and replaces newline's fine for 'English' (western?) text, but does some odd things for other languages.
Greek & Arabic text seems to get newlines added to it using this replacement string method.

I've tried matching on \p{Zl} (Found in CPAN-perlunicode.pod) eg:

```
$txtin =~ s/\p{Z1}\s*/ \\ /g;
```

But that leaves \n in westernized tweets, so it's not matching what I'd expected / hoped for.

So basically, my question is: How do I replace all newline / cr characters in a utf8 blob of text (a tweet), that will work for cyrillic, arabic, kanji & western content in Perl?

Thank you!

---

EDIT: If you missed the first edit and read this far, this is a question based on a false assumption. It wasn't the newline stripping causing the problem. Apparently it's a text wrap problem totally unrelated to the above. This question now flagged for moderation (since I can't delete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh. Apparently this is one way to close it. See EDIT's in original. Apparently it's a word wrap problem, not related to stripping out newlines.

Answer (score 3):

`\\` matches a single backslash character, so `/\\p{Z1}/` matches a backslash, and then the literal string `p{Z1}`. To match the character class `\p{Z1}`, you'll either want one more or one fewer backslash at the beginning of the regular expression, depending on whether the input contains backslashes.

Comment: Ouch. My first question on here and I manage to get that wrong when I type it.

Answer (score 3):

`s/\\n\s*/ \\ /g` does not strip out and replace newline's fine for 'English' (western?) text<sup>[1]</sup>, and it doesn't add newlines for Greek and Arabic text. I don't know what you did use, but to replace a newline optionally followed by whitespace, you use the following on the decoded text:

```
s/\n\s*/.../g
```

- `\n` matches a newline.
- `\\n` matches a the two characters `\n`.
- `\p{Z1}` matches U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR (but not a newline).
- `\\p{Z1}` matches the 6 characters `\p{Z1}`.
- A newline is a newline, no matter what other characters might be near it.

> *How do I replace all newline / cr characters in a utf8 blob of text (a tweet), that will work for cyrillic, arabic, kanji & western content in Perl?*

A newline is a newline no matter what other characters may be near it. Same goes for carriage returns.

```
utf8::decode( my $unicode_chars = $utf8_bytes );
$unicode_chars =~ s/[\r\n]/.../g;
utf8::encode( $utf8_bytes = $unicode_chars );
```

Or maybe you're asking how to replace vertical whitespace characters?

```
utf8::decode( my $unicode_chars = $utf8_bytes );
$unicode_chars =~ s/\v/.../g;
utf8::encode( $utf8_bytes = $unicode_chars );
```

---

Notes:

1. Unless they happen to follow a backslash and an "n".

Comment: `s/\\n\s*/ \\ /g;` does strip out newlines (and replaces with a ' \ '). See edit for foul up on the arabic rendering problems. The "\p{Z1} matches U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR (but not a newline)" bit was useful. $txtin was already in unicode_chars.

Comment: @Fluffkin, No, it doesn't (unless they follow a backslash newline (which would also get removed))

Comment: @Fluffkin, Compare output of `perl -e"$_=chr(0x0A); s/\\n/NEWLINE/g; printf qq{%v02X\n}, $_"` with `perl -e"$_=chr(0x0A); s/\n/NEWLINE/g; printf qq{%v02X\n}, $_"`. (Change " to ' on unix)

Comment: That should be "backslash 'n'", not "backslash newline" in my earlier comment.

Comment: Looks at screen output. In this scenario it does. Turns out that the new newline's in arabic text etc comes from the word wrap feature (which is applied after stripping the original \n sequences). Not even Text::Wrap seems to cope with it.

Comment: Re "Looks at screen output.", The code in question doesn't output anything to the screen. You appear to be looking at the output of something completely irrelevant. Re "In this scenario it does", No. There's nothing you can do to cause `s/\\n/.../g` to replace newlines. It replaces backslash "n". Maybe that's what you want to do, but that's completely different than what you've asked.

Comment: Anyway, this isn't helping move things forward. Is there a problem that still needs to be addressed? If so, what is it? If not, please accept an answer.

Comment: I'm looking at the text field output given from TTYtter as described. `s/\\n\s*/ \\ /g;` does indeed strip out newlines from the text. I'm sorry if this doesn't fit your world view. See EDIT on original post which is now flagged for moderation (I can't delete it).

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can't prove it doesn't (proving a negaitve), so it's up to you to prove you have a very very very broken Perl. (It's very easy to do. Just provide a dump of the variable before and after the s///. Use `$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1` for best results.) It's much more likely that you're not looking at the right thing, since `s/\\n\s*/ \\ /g` doesn't operate on text fields.

Comment: Before `$VAR1 = 'RT @xxx: riding \\u2018gainst the skyline ~ \\nacross the full moon ~ \\ncoach and horses \\n\\n#haiku #micropoetry #poetry';`
After `$VAR1 = 'RT @xxx: riding \\u2018gainst the skyline ~  \\ across the full moon ~  \\ coach and horses  \\  \\ #haiku #micropoetry #poetry';`

Comment: @Fluffkin, There are no newlines in the input.  Like I said, it removed backslash+"n" character pairs. (Looks like an improperly-parsed JSON fragment.)

Comment: "Perl uses \n to represent the "logical" newline" from perldoc.org. So you're telling me perldoc is wrong?